# Lazy loading doesn't load the module - Angular 8

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular8, angular-routing

I'm trying to lazy load my home page which includes a PrimeNG module (MenubarModule), but it is never loaded so I keep getting the error:

> Error: Template parse errors:
> 'p-menubar' is not a known element:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    PanelModule,
    InputTextModule,
    ButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MenubarModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

@edit
If I put my MenubarModule in my app.module, it will work, but I want it to be lazy loaded inside my home.module

Comment: where is p-menubar component defined?

Comment: He is in my home.component.html
If i put the MenuBarModule in my app..module, everithing work, but this isn't a lazy load, right?

Comment: I think you are not getting it. Can you create a stackblitz/plunkr for your problem?

Comment: Take a look 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7da3ap?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do in your stackblitz to fix the code

index.html should be

```
<body><app-root></app-root></body>
```

whereas you had some different entry tag than `app-root`

Also you need to remove all the references to your HomeComponent from the app module and app route module and add the `forChild` router definition in your Home Module as

```
RouterModule.forChild([{ path: "", component: HomeComponent }])
```

Working stackblitz at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fu9rx5

Comment: Many thanks! U solved it!
Just one more thing, can u explain me, why it's working now? What i make wrong?

Answer (score 0):

app.module.ts :

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(module => module.HomeModule)},
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(login => login.LoginModule)}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
<br>
<a routerLink="/login">Login</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

home.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
     { path: 'some', component: SomeComponent }
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

login.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

login-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent, children: [
     { path: 'another', component: AnotherComponent }
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

And now it have to work. Becouse of `children:` You can use in `LoginComponent` and `HomeComponent` a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` dom element.

Comment: Did You try not in StackBlitz ? But in Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: @M4ESTRO Updated.

Comment: @M4ESTRO I did an mistake about bootstrap components in lazy loading modules i update answear. XD

Answer (score 0):

If You are trying to lazy load, you should declare your child components in `home.module.ts` and define route in `home-routing.module.ts` then it will work.

[image]

From the above image `admin.module.ts`, it has two components as `home` and `settings` now lets see the `admin-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';


export const AdminRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  children: [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }]
}];
```

and those `AdminRoutes` are imported to `admin.module.ts` and the components are declared in the following way.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminRoutes } from './admin-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, SettingsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(AdminRoutes)
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

and then you define it the lazy load in `app-routing.module.ts` it will work for good.